# Jquery updating text in editable div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm currently working on a page to generate questions for a Hangman-type of quiz.

In order to do this and to keep it as dummyproof as possible for the people that are going to be using this application, I've created a Editable div where the Hangman is being shown as it will appear to the players.

The goal is that the users can type in the hangman in the div and every time they enter a character, the character is "embedded" in HTML-code. This HTML code puts the character in a separate div with a background-image in it and specific layout. Underneath every box there's also a button which is generated to be able to toggle the visibility on the character. This case the person who is inputting can make characters visible or invisible to make the hangman easier or harder.

So I have got this working, see the fiddle below, but I still have a few problems:

- I would like to center the entire hangman. Is there an easy jQuery-way do to do this or do I need to count the characters and calculate an offset for every div?
- If a user wants to edit a piece of the hangman (eg in case of a typo) he can remove the character by placing the caret before the character and hitting the delete button. But the backspace doesn't work.
  Also I've added a function to set the caret at the end of the last character in the div when replacing the character with the "embedded" character. But when you edit the hangman, this is annoying because if you want to add more characters at a given position, the caret always jumps back at the end. So is there a way to keep the caret at the position where the users add text?
- If a user types a space, I want this to result in a spacer but without the button. However you will see in the fiddle that the if-code is never being called. And I have no idea why.

  $.each(arrContent, function(){

  ```
      if (this == " ")
      {
          $("#Hangman").append('<div class="Space">&nbsp;</div>');            
      }
      else
      {
          $("#Hangman").append('<div class="box" id="Box"><p class="hangmanContent">' + this.toUpperCase() + '<input type="button" class="button" value="' + this.toUpperCase() + '"></input></p></div>');
      }

  });
  ```

A part of the project can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/8f401k5w/
In order to make it more easy to read, I've only included the relevant code and some the of the images have been replaced by background color because I couldn't store the images.

I know I could easily solve these issues by using a textbox where the users enter the text, but it would cause an issue with the layout so theirfor I'm hesitant to do it. However I'll keep it as a last resort.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I think it will be almost impossible to get this to work with a `contentEditable` div. If you really don't want to use a plain input, you could create your own editor using a div that accepts keyboard input. You can create such a div by giving it a `tabindex` attribute. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4brsgrkf/) is an idea of what you could do.

Comment: To be honest, that's what I'm also afraid of. I already made a second version with the input-field. But there are many things I don't know so maybe there is a way, I just haven't found it. But thank you for your effort and also the idea on the template in your example.